# Building LÖVE, no yum package DevIL-devel available for CentOS 6, needing build guidance

Tags: build, rpm, yum, centos6, devil

I am trying to build the LÖVE framework for CentOS 6, using an i686 architecture.  I have had very little success building the dependency DevIL-devel.  I could not find any existing yum package for LÖVE, so that is why I attempted to build in the first place.

I have found some rpms, DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686.rpm, which requires further dependencies, found in DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686.rpm and DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686.rpm.

These however, have dependencies of their own, which seem to require each other and unavailable dependencies.

Output from uname -a: Linux jkyrouac 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 14:27:42 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

## yum --nogpgcheck localinstall DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686.rpm

...

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: DevIL = 1.7.8-8mgc26

Error: Package: DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libIL.so.1

Error: Package: DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-devel-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libILU.so.1

## yum --nogpgcheck localinstall DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686.rpm

...

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5

Error: Package: DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15

Error: Package: DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)

Here, libtiff and libpng are installed, so not sure what other package(s) are needed.

## yum --nogpgcheck localinstall DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686.rpm

...

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: DevIL = 1.7.8-8mgc26

Error: Package: DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libIL.so.1

Error: Package: DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: liballeg.so.4.4

Error: Package: DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15

Error: Package: DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5

Error: Package: DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686 (/DevIL-ILUT-1.7.8-8mgc26.i686)
           Requires: libILU.so.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages you're trying to install seem to be for Mageia Cauldron (mgc), so I doubt they will work on CentOS.  Even if you have the dependencies installed, I imagine they won't be where a Mageia package is expecting to find them.

Comment: I was working on this project for several hours, and it seemed that at the time of writing there was simply a lack of support for DevIL.  I ended up building and testing the Love library on another distro where it performed fine.  I appreciate the insight as to why package manager was getting so confused, having never heard of Mageia Cauldron until now.